# How to allocate buffer within 32-bit address space?

Tags: c, linux, arm, 32bit-64bit, memory-address

I would like to allocate a buffer within 32-bit address space on 64-bit ARM. In other words, I would like to ensure that my buffer is bound to the lower 32-bit address space. Do you know a nice C function which does that?

Comment: User space? physical and logical (virtual) addresses are unrelated. So you can have 32bit address, but maybe above 32bit. In any case, it is possible, but you must provide more information about size and use: you should tell the kernel to allocate and make such memory fixed, usually linked to some hardware.

Comment: Seems like XY problem. Could you share your original intent? Why do you need to be allocated in lower 32 bits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no C standard function to do so. However, since you tagged the question as Linux, take a look at [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_32BIT` flags, e.g.:

```
mmap(
    0, 1,
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_32BIT,
    -1, 0
);
```

Another option is passing an explicit address in the lower 32-bit address space using the `MAP_FIXED` flag:

```
mmap(
    (void *)0x10000, 1,
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED,
    -1, 0
);
```